# How vbscript to open Mstsc?

Tags: vbscript

Where do i did mistake? i'm unable to run this script. Nothing is open. Kindly help/guide me.

this is vbscript.

```
Dim WSH

Set WSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WSH.RUN ("""MSTSC C:\Temp\EUE test\HCC-MSYS10 - Test.RDP""")
```

Comment: Is this VB.NET, VBScript, VBA or VB6?

Comment: I have removed the unrelated tags

Answer (score 1):

Quote the argument not the entire command;

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("MSTSC ""C:\Temp\EUE test\HCC-MSYS10 - Test.RDP""")
```

Or just:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("""C:\Temp\EUE test\HCC-MSYS10 - Test.RDP""")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it working fine. when i change as below its not working at all. any idea? and giving error "Invalid connection file (C:\Temp\EEE test\Resolution - 1024 by 768 - New\KUU (Kuuuu Lllll) - ABCD123456) specified. 
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("MSTSC ""C:\Temp\EEE test\Resolution - 1024 by 768 - New\KUU (Kuuuu Lllll) - ABCD123456""")

Comment: the .rdp is there. i can run the .rdp without any error directly.

Comment: I mean there is no .rdp in the path string

Comment: Ok i got it. sorry i miss the .rdp :( sorry for the silly mistake.